# Export images with document studio with format

Tags: google-docs

I tried to export images from a Google Spreadsheet linked to my Google form and I succeded. The problem is when the images have different dimensions.
Is there a way to generate some preset so that when you insert it, adapts to a certain shape??

I'm using {{image}} to recall it from the spreadsheet and the link to Google drive there: https://drive.google.com/open...

I need a template with an image always using the same space, not a different one for each photo dimension.

Comment: Welcome. Please do share your efforts. Also do [How to 
Ask](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [About 
asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make the template with Google Slides and insert a text box and in format options of the box you can block the aspect relation.

I had the same problem and this trick works.